# jScrollPane with percent padding missing right border?

Tags: jscrollpane, padding

I am using jScrollPane on an element that has a 1px border and % padding to inset the div contents. All looks fine when first displayed.

When I resize the window down I reinitialise jScrollPane and my right border disappears. It appears that the % padding is not recalculated, the pixel values from the full screen display are retained and used in calculating the new element width, causing the right border to be outside the viewable area.

Any suggestions on how to fix this, or a workaround, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to destroy the api before recreating the jScrollPane like this:

```
var pane = $('.scroll-pane');
var api = pane.data('jsp');
api.destroy();
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
```